# multiline regex pattern that match 3 digits

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

Can anyone please help me with a regex pattern that will match and check the following scenarios? I'm trying to match text that's separated with return characters. Each line should only have 3 digits (\d{3}) in it and up to 100 lines.

This is ok:

```
123
456
789
```

This is not ok:

```
123
123789
456
```

This is not ok (note the empty line in the middle and at end):

```
123

456
```

I would appreciate any suggestion and help. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the entire file must look like this? Then try

```
new Regex(@"\A(?:\d{3}\r?\n)*\z")
```

**Explanation:**

```
\A     # Start of string
(?:    # Match the following (non-capturing) group:
 \d{3} #  - three digits
 \r?\n #  - one CRLF or LF (linebreak)
)*     # any number of times (0 or more)
\z     # until the very end of the string
```

If the file might not end with a newline (not sure from your description), you can use

```
new Regex(@"\A(?:\d{3}\r?$\n?)*\z", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

This initially makes newlines optional (`\r?\n?`) but ensures that there is a line ending after every three-character bit by placing the end-of-line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` between CR and LF, which is where (strangely) .NET thinks it should match.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. This works out wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is simply to check each line against your initial regex (\d{3}).
Another way is to add \r \n to your regex and allow for repeats

```
"(\d{3}\r?\n)*"
```

in order to filter out case 3, you just need to add beginning and end to show you want to match the entire file; (^ specifies beginning, $ specifies end)

```
"^(\d{3}\r?\n)*$"
```